# Dynamically create filter and matching checkboxes in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have many data points, with several types;

JSON file:

```
{
  "items":[
    {
      "id:": 1,
      "type": "type1", //typeN isn't tied to id=N
      ... : ...
    },
    {
      "id:": 2,
      "type": "anotherType",
      ... : ...
    },
    {...},{...},{...},...
  ]
}
```

I want to filter these results with checkboxes in the DOM.  So first I want to get them into the DOM. So I need to find the unique types in the data.  I do this through this function in the Controller:

```
var itemTypeList = function(){
  if ($scope.hasOwnProperty('allItems')){ //this is to ensure async load completed
    var uniqTypes = [];
    for (var i=0 ; i < $scope.allItems.length ; i++){
      if (uniqTypes.indexOf($scope.allItems[i].type) < 0){
        uniqTypes.push($scope.allItems[i].type);
      }
    }
    $scope.uniqTypes = uniqTypes;
    return $scope.uniqTypes;
  }
};
```

and then I place them in the HTML like so:

```
<!-- These are what will be shown/hidden -->
<div class="">
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="item in allItems | filter:showItem">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>

<!-- this is the filter section -->
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="uT in uniqTypes">
  <label>{{uT}}</label>
  <!-- here is where the accompanying checkbox should go -->
</div>
```

So far, my Controller Filter looks like this:

```
$scope.showItem = function(item){
   return item.type === $scope.Filter.item1 || 
     item.type === $scope.Filter.type2;
     //this is static, and I only typed 2 of the many....
};
```

and the input check box looks like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.uT" ng-true-value="{{uT}}"/><br/>
```

The problem is that the filter is static, and I had to manually put in the types.  The second problem is that the checkbox ng-model can't be defined like so `ng-model="Filter.{{uT}}"`.  I can only find examples of statically defined models.   How do I change the filter and the input ng-repeat to use the uniqueTypes (uT) that I have already found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't see the whole picture, but it seems like you want something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="uT in uniqTypes">
  <label>{{uT}}</label>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter[uT]"/>
</div>
```

value of checkbox will be true or false -->  $scope.Filter.type2 will be true/false

```
$scope.Filter = {};

$scope.showItem = function(item){
   return $scope.Filter[item.type];
};
```

will return true  or false

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dTLfE/) of the basic version

If you want to have them showing initially, and click to unhide, the `$scope.Filter` needs to be populated first by a key[val] pair.  This can be done when you dynamically create the `uniqueTypes` list.

Here is this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrisfrisina/dTLfE/4/) of it showing and checked initially

Comment: The `ng-model='Filter[uT]'` is not evaluating to `ng-model='Filter[type1]'` or `ng-model='Filter[type2]'` in the DOM.  And I get the error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'type1' of undefined` when checking a box

Comment: It's evaluating to `ng-model="Filter['type1']"`. It throws an error because Filter ($scope.Filter) is undefined, not because it doesn't evaluate. You've forgotten to write `$scope.Filter = {};` in your controller, didn't you? :)

Comment: Yes.  Didnt know the diff between an object and an associative array in JS.  SO this took some working through. `Yay!` for working now, NO `Yay!` for unconventional introduction to CS and programming in one year...  Thanks!   Ive updated the answer to include $scope.Filter